# Error when I install wubi in windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386 for 32 bit(less than 2 gb ram) and inside iso when i run wubi installer directly showing an error showing in temp file wubi-14.04-rev286 and not installing.I have tried same for ubuntu 12.04 also but same problem persist and an error that is shown in folder wubi-12.04-rev266 temp file.Thats why i am unable to install any of ubuntu version.I have urgent need to install it.Please someone help.....

Comment: Wubi sometimes has problems. Can you try booting from USB instead of using Wubi.